# Slow wordcloud in R

Tags: r

Trying to create a word cloud from a 300MB .csv file with text, but its taking hours on a decent laptop with 16GB of RAM. Not sure how long this should typically take...but here's my code:

```
library("tm")
library("SnowballC")
library("wordcloud")
library("RColorBrewer")

dfTemplate <- read.csv("CleanedDescMay.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

template <- dfTemplate
template <- Corpus(VectorSource(template))
template <- tm_map(template, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
template <- tm_map(template, stripWhitespace)
template <- tm_map(template, removePunctuation)

dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(template)

m <- as.matrix(dtm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m), decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v), freq=v)
head(d, 10)


par(bg="grey30")
png(file="WordCloudDesc1.png", width=1000, height=700, bg="grey30")
wordcloud(d$word, d$freq, col=terrain.colors(length(d$word), alpha=0.9), random.order=FALSE, rot.per = 0.3, max.words=500)
title(main = "Top Template Words", font.main=1, col.main="cornsilk3",    cex.main=1.5)
dev.off()
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: I don't know what the `wordcloud` function is doing internally, but since you only want 500 words plotted why not just give it the first 500 words? `wordcloud(head(d$word, 500), head(d$freq, 500), ...)`

Answer (score 2):

#### Step 1: Profile

Have you tried profiling your full workflow yet with a small subset to figure out which steps are taking the most time? [Profiling with RStudio here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/218221837-Profiling-with-RStudio)

If not, that should be your first step.

#### If the `tm_map()` functions are taking a long time:

If I recall correctly, I found working with `stringi` to be faster than the dedicated corpus tools.

My workflow wound up looking like the following for the pre-cleaning steps. This could definitely be optimized further -- `magrittr` pipes `%>%` do contribute to some additional processing time, but I feel like that's an acceptable trade-off for the sanity of not having dozens of nested parenthesis.

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)
library(parallel)


## This function handles the processing pipeline
textCleaner <- function(InputText, StopWords, Words, NewWords){
  InputText %>% 
    stri_enc_toascii(.) %>% 
    toupper(.) %>% 
    stri_replace_all_regex(.,"[[:cntrl:]]"," ") %>% 
    stri_replace_all_regex(.,"[[:punct:]]"," ") %>% 
    stri_replace_all_regex(.,"[[:space:]]+"," ") %>% ## Replaces multiple spaces with 
    stri_replace_all_regex(.,"^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$","") %>% ## Remove leading and trailing spaces
    stri_replace_all_regex(.,"\\b"%s+%StopWords%s+%"\\b","",vectorize_all = FALSE) %>%  ## Stopwords
    stri_replace_all_regex(.,"\\b"%s+%Words%s+%"\\b",NewWords,vectorize_all = FALSE) ## Replacements
}




## Replacement Words, I would normally read in a .CSV file
Replace <- data.table(Old = c("LOREM","IPSUM","DOLOR","SIT"),
                      New = c("I","DONT","KNOW","LATIN"))

## These need to be defined globally
GlobalStopWords <- c("AT","UT","IN","ET","A")
GlobalOldWords <- Replace[["Old"]]
GlobalNewWords <- Replace[["New"]]

## Generate some sample text
DT <- data.table(Text = stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(500000))

## Running Single Threaded
system.time({
  DT[,CleanedText := textCleaner(Text, GlobalStopWords,GlobalOldWords, GlobalNewWords)]
})
#   user  system elapsed 
# 66.969   0.747  67.802
```

The process of cleaning text is embarrassingly parallel, so in theory you should be able some big time savings possible with multiple cores.

I used to run this pipeline in parallel, but looking back at it today, it turns out that the communication overhead makes this take twice as long with 8 cores as it does single threaded. I'm not sure if this was the same for my original use case, but I guess this may simply serve as a good example of why trying to parallelize instead of optimize can lead to more trouble than value.

```
## This function handles the cluster creation
    ## and exporting libraries, functions, and objects
    parallelCleaner <- function(Text, NCores){
      cl <- parallel::makeCluster(NCores)
      clusterEvalQ(cl, library(magrittr))
      clusterEvalQ(cl, library(stringi))
      clusterExport(cl, list("textCleaner",
                             "GlobalStopWords",
                             "GlobalOldWords",
                             "GlobalNewWords"))
      Text <- as.character(unlist(parallel::parLapply(cl, Text,
                                                      fun = function(x) textCleaner(x,
                                                                                    GlobalStopWords,
                                                                                    GlobalOldWords,
                                                                                    GlobalNewWords))))
      parallel::stopCluster(cl)
      return(Text)
    }

    ## Run it Parallel
    system.time({
      DT[,CleanedText := parallelCleaner(Text = Text,
                                         NCores =  8)]
    }) 
#   user  system elapsed 
#  6.700   5.099 131.429
```

#### If the `TermDocumentMatrix(template)` is the chief offender:

---

> Update: I mentioned Drew Schmidt and Christian Heckendorf also submitted an R package named `ngram` to CRAN recently that might be worth checking out: [`ngram` Github Repository](https://github.com/wrathematics/ngram). Turns out I should have just tried it before explaining the really cumbersome process of building a command line tool from source-- this would have saved me a lot of time had been around 18 months ago!

It is a good deal more memory intensive and not *quite* as fast -- my memory usage peaked around 31 GB so that may or may not be a deal-breaker for you. All things considered, this seems like a really good option.

For the 500,000 paragraph case, `ngrams` clocks in at around 7 minutes of runtime:

```
#install.packages("ngram")
library(ngram)
library(data.table)
system.time({
  ng1 <- ngram::ngram(DT[["CleanedText"]],n = 1)
  ng2 <- ngram::ngram(DT[["CleanedText"]],n = 2)
  ng3 <- ngram::ngram(DT[["CleanedText"]],n = 3)

  pt1 <- setDT(ngram::get.phrasetable(ng1))
  pt1[,Ngrams := 1L]
  pt2 <- setDT(ngram::get.phrasetable(ng2))
  pt2[,Ngrams := 2L]
  pt3 <- setDT(ngram::get.phrasetable(ng3))
  pt3[,Ngrams := 3L]

  pt <- rbindlist(list(pt1,pt2,pt3))
})

#    user  system elapsed 
# 411.671  12.177 424.616 

pt[Ngrams == 2][order(-freq)][1:5]

#      ngrams  freq         prop Ngrams
# 1: SED SED  75096 0.0018013693      2
# 2:  AC SED  33390 0.0008009444      2
# 3:  SED AC  33134 0.0007948036      2
# 4:  SED EU  30379 0.0007287179      2
# 5:  EU SED  30149 0.0007232007      2
```

---

You can try using a more efficient `ngram` generator. I use a command line tool called `ngrams` [(available on github here)](https://github.com/jerry2yu/ngrams) by  Zheyuan Yu-   partial implementation of  Dr. Vlado Keselj 's Text-Ngrams 1.6 to take pre-processed text files off disk and generate a .csv output with ngram frequencies.

You'll need to build from source yourself using `make` and then interface with it using `system()` calls from `R`, but I found it to run orders of magnitude faster while using a tiny fraction of the memory. Using it, I was was able generate 5-grams from ~700MB of text input in well under an hour, the CSV result with all the output was 2.9 GB file with 93 million rows.

Continuing the example above, In my working directory, I have a folder, `ngrams-master`, in my working directory that contains the `ngrams` executable created with `make`.

```
writeLines(DT[["CleanedText"]],con = "ExampleText.txt")
system2(command = "ngrams-master/ngrams",args = "--type=word --n = 3 --in ExampleText.txt", stdout = "ExampleGrams.csv")

# ngrams have been generated, start outputing.
# Subtotal: 165 seconds for generating ngrams.
# Subtotal: 12 seconds for outputing ngrams.
# Total 177 seconds.
Grams <- fread("ExampleGrams.csv")
# Read 5917978 rows and 3 (of 3) columns from 0.160 GB file in 00:00:06
Grams[Ngrams == 3 & Frequency > 10][sample(.N,5)]
#    Ngrams Frequency                  Token
# 1:      3        11 INTERDUM_NEC_RIDICULUS
# 2:      3        18  MAURIS_PORTTITOR_ERAT
# 3:      3        14      SOCIIS_AMET_JUSTO
# 4:      3        23  EGET_TURPIS_FERMENTUM
# 5:      3        14  VENENATIS_LIGULA_NISL
```

I think I may have made a couple tweaks to get the output format how I wanted it, if you're interested I can try to find the changes I made to generate a `.csv`outputs that differ from the default and upload to Github. *(I did that project before I was familiar with the platform so I don't have a good record of the changes I made, live and learn.)*

> Update 2: I created a fork on Github, [msummersgill/ngrams](https://github.com/msummersgill/ngrams) that reflects the slight tweaks I made to output results in a .CSV format. If someone was so inclined, I have a hunch that this could be wrapped up in a `Rcpp` based package that would be acceptable for CRAN submission -- any takers? I honestly have no clue how Ternary Search Trees work, but they seem to be **significantly** more memory efficient and faster than any other N-gram implementation currently available in R.

Drew Schmidt and Christian Heckendorf also submitted an R package named `ngram` to CRAN, I haven't used it personally but it might be worth checking out as well: [`ngram` Github Repository](https://github.com/wrathematics/ngram).

#### The Whole Shebang:

Using the same pipeline described above but with a size closer to what you're dealing with *(`ExampleText.txt` comes out to ~274MB)*:

```
DT <- data.table(Text = stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(500000))

system.time({
  DT[,CleanedText := textCleaner(Text, GlobalStopWords,GlobalOldWords, GlobalNewWords)]
})
#   user  system elapsed 
# 66.969   0.747  67.802 

writeLines(DT[["CleanedText"]],con = "ExampleText.txt")
system2(command = "ngrams-master/ngrams",args = "--type=word --n = 3 --in ExampleText.txt", stdout = "ExampleGrams.csv")

# ngrams have been generated, start outputing.
# Subtotal: 165 seconds for generating ngrams.
# Subtotal: 12 seconds for outputing ngrams.
# Total 177 seconds.
Grams <- fread("ExampleGrams.csv")
# Read 5917978 rows and 3 (of 3) columns from 0.160 GB file in 00:00:06
Grams[Ngrams == 3 & Frequency > 10][sample(.N,5)]
#    Ngrams Frequency                  Token
# 1:      3        11 INTERDUM_NEC_RIDICULUS
# 2:      3        18  MAURIS_PORTTITOR_ERAT
# 3:      3        14      SOCIIS_AMET_JUSTO
# 4:      3        23  EGET_TURPIS_FERMENTUM
# 5:      3        14  VENENATIS_LIGULA_NISL
```

While the example may not be a perfect representation due to the limited vocabulary generated by `stringi::stri_rand_lipsum()`, the total run time of ~4.2 minutes using less than 8 GB of RAM on 500,000 paragraphs has been fast enough for the corpuses (corpi?) I've had to tackle in the past.

#### If wordcloud() is the source of the slowdown:

I'm not familiar with this function, but @Gregor's comment on your original post seems like it would take care of this issue.

```
library(wordcloud)
GramSubset <- Grams[Ngrams == 2][1:500]
par(bg="gray50")
wordcloud(GramSubset[["Token"]],GramSubset[["Frequency"]],color = GramSubset[["Frequency"]],
          rot.per = 0.3,font.main=1, col.main="cornsilk3",    cex.main=1.5)
```

[image: wordcloud]

Comment: Wow, what an answer! It doesn't seem that formal profiling is needed, though, these steps are discrete in the code, so the OP can just go through them one by one and see where the time is being taken.

Comment: *Corpora* or *corpuses*